# Android: SingleChoiceItems doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a Dialog Single Choice Radio Button group but when I execute my code the RadioButton Group doesn't appear.
Can you please help me?

Code:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private int selected1 = 0;
final CharSequence myList[] = { "A", "B" };

public void currency(){


    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Test");

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(myList, selected1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            selected1 = which;
            Log.d("BaseActivity", "selected--->" + selected1);
        }

    });

    builder.create();

    builder.show();
```

Comment: is the currency() method being run at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it says in the javadoc of AlertDialog:

> If you only want to
>     display a String in this dialog box, use the setMessage() method.

So you have to change

```
builder.setMessage("Test");
```

for

```
builder.setTitle("Test");
```

If you want to know more about dialogs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html